# How to get (tray) icon path/image in electron-builder

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I'm using [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate) to develop electron app (which uses [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) to pack apps).

I want to create tray, but it requires icon path or native image. The question is how to retrieve icon image from electron-builder or how to tell electron-builder to include icons dir into resources (without packing), so I can use:

`appIcon = new Tray(iconPath | nativeImage)`

Answer (score 10):

I kind of struggled with a solution about non-packaged assets (such as media or JSON config files), mostly because I was not familiar with Electron until now. :)
I built a simple personal tray-only app and I didn't want to repackage every time I change an icon for instance.

If you too plan on using changing/dynamic assets you can distinguish between "development" and "production" using this property:
https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appispackaged-readonly

Make sure you have this in your package.json:

```
"build": {
  ...
  "extraResources": [
    "./assets/**"
  ],
}
```

https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents#extraresources

Then in your code you can have:

```
const assetsPath = app.isPackaged ? path.join(process.resourcesPath, "assets") : "assets";
```

Of course you can also use a different path for storing assets, independent of your packaged app folder, for example your user's home or user's documents:

https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appgetpathname

- Electron v7.0.1
- electron-builder 21.2.0

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  Yours is the only one that worked and worked well.  I didn't even know about that extraResources option

Comment: But is it necessary to use extraResources?  Because without using extraResources my assets are copied correctly to my dist/AppName/assets folder and I select an icon from there so I do not understand why mine would not work. My other icons work correctly without extraResources so must the tray icon lie in a resources file to work correctly?

Answer (score 6):

Firstly you need to tell `electron-builder` which extra files need copying into your output build. I copy over native drivers for each os like below, but you should be able to adapt this to your needs. The `"to": "resources"` means you'll be able to use the next code to find the files later.

```
"build": {
...
"extraFiles": [
  {
    "from": "resources/${os}/drivers",
    "to": "resources",
    "filter": [
      "**/*"
    ]
  }
],
```

Then to get access to that path from in electron you can use:

```
const path = require('path');
const imgPath = path.join(process.resourcesPath, 'image.png')
```

If you're in the main process you can omit the `remote` part.

You can then use [nativeImage.createFromPath](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/native-image/#nativeimagecreatefrompathpath) to get a native image:

```
const nativeImage = require('electron').nativeImage
let image = nativeImage.createFromPath(imgPath)
```

Comment: You can use [process.resourcesPath](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/process.md#processresourcespath) to get path to the resources directory

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, Tim, your answer gave me a good thought. I reused it with some addition depending on how I run my app - form vs code using electron or from installed deb file:

```
"build": {
    ...
    "extraFiles": [
        {
            "from": "assets",
            "to": "resources",
            "filter": [
                "**/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
    ...
}
```

And then:

```
let imgPath = process.env.DEV ? "assets/icon.png" : path.join(process.resourcesPath, "icon.png");
tray = new Tray(imgPath);
```